# Error 404 while senting data to server

Tags: android, json

This code is supposed to be sending my JSON value to the server. When I click the button, I get an error - `Unexpected reponse code 404.`

Could someone explain what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Is this a server side error?

This is my code...

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
      getResults();
      StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,server_url,new Response.Listener<String>() {

          @Override 
          public void onResponse(String response){

          }
      },new Response.ErrorListener(){
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

          }
        })

    {
    protected Map<String,String>getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
    Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    getResults().put(parameters);

return parameters;
}
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}


private JSONArray getResults() {

    String myPath = "/data/data/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails/databases/" + "MyDBName.db";

    String myTable = "patients";


    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);

    JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        object.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));

                    } else {
                        object.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }

                    jsonArray.put(object);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } 
        jsonArray.put(rowObject);
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return resultSet;
}
}
```

Comment: PRovide more data: url name, lib are you using , etc

Comment: Make sure that the url you're calling is present or not. There are chances that either the url you're calling is wrong or there is no such end point.

Answer (score 1):

404 means not found, `server_url` points to a not existent URL or the page you are requesting is redirecting you to 404.

If you open a browser and send a POST request in AJAX to the same URL and the same parameters, then you should experience the same behavior.